# How to unset when only knowing a key's numerical order

Tags: php, arrays, unset

I'm wanting to unset from an array but I only know each key by it's numerical order.

What's the best way to remove them?

```
$arr = [
    'horse' => true,
    'rabbit' => false,
    'cat' => true,
    'dog' => false,
    'sheep' => false,
];

$remove = [0,1,3];
```

Desired result:

```
$arr = [
    'cat' => true,
    'sheep' => false,
];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `array_keys` to get the actual keys, then use the indexes to get the corresponding keys.

```
$arr_keys = array_keys($arr);
foreach ($remove as $r) {
    unset($arr[$arr_keys[$r]]);
}
```

Comment: I like this answer for its shortness.

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this,

```
$counter = 0;
foreach($arr as $key => $value){
    if(in_array($counter, $remove)){
        unset($arr[$key]);
    }
    ++$counter;
}

// display $arr array
var_dump($arr);
```

Here's the [**live demo**](https://eval.in/590457)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a fun way:

```
$arr = array_intersect_key($arr,
                           array_flip(array_diff_key(array_keys($arr),
                                                     array_flip($remove))));
```

- Flip the remove array to get the values as keys
- Get the difference between those keys and the integer keys of the main array
- Flip that and get the values of the keys that intersect with the main array

Here's more fun:

```
$arr = array_filter($arr, function($v) use($remove) {
                                static $k = 0; return !in_array($k++, $remove);
                          });
```

- Filter the array using a function that increments a counter starting from 0
- Return `true` if the counter is not `!` in the remove array and `false` if it is

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `array_keys` (http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php).

```
<?php
$arr = [
    'horse' => true,
    'rabbit' => false,
    'cat' => true,
    'dog' => false,
    'sheep' => false,
];
$keys = array_keys($arr);

$remove = [0,1,3];

foreach($remove as $key) {
    unset($arr[$keys[$key]]);
}

var_dump($arr);
```

Comment: @mistermartin Sorry. From the PHP documentation: array_keys() returns the keys, numeric and string, from the array. Returns an array of all the keys in array.

Comment: your foreach says `$key` when it's actually the value.

Comment: Yes. @mistermartin Please look carefully. The array is `$remove` here which is containing the value of the indexes that need to be deleted.

Comment: You overwrote `$arr` with its keys-only by doing `$arr = array_keys($arr);`

Comment: I'm just pointing out that this code is confusing. Arrays have both keys and values, and you're referring to the value as the key.

Comment: Now it's exactly the same as my answer. Even the variable name is the same.

Comment: @Barmar so should I remove my answer?

Comment: Or just change the variable names like you did.  But I would delete it.